# mysql delete row if all null after update without trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

For a certain table, if a field is updated to Null and all fields for that row are now Null I want to delete this row. I understand this can be done with a trigger, but I have heard that triggers should be avoided whenever possible. Is there another solution to this which avoids triggers, and has lower cost? How expensive would a trigger even be in this case (is it less expensive than running two queries?)

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

1. Put in  a DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD ==NULL after every update.
2. Use a trigger
3. Centralize all updates through a stored procedure so that you can call the SP when you update the record, which can then call the DELETE FROM command in #1.

Comment: how expensive is each of these options?

Comment: #3 has the least amount of 'overhead' in that it provides both the most concise code AND it doesn't have the overhead of a trigger. 

The challenge is that another programmer can come along and still code an update to the table that doesn't use the stored procedure. If you want to guard against that kind of ... problem ... then you need to use a Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers should not be avoided wherever possible.  They should just be used with discretion.

First, in many systems that I've been involved with, all the DML operations are embedded in stored procedures.  Basically, anything a trigger would do is in the stored procedure -- along with other functionality such as logging.

Second, if you have a problem that requires a trigger, then use a trigger.  For instance, prior to Oracle 12C, you needed a trigger to add an auto-incrementing primary key.  By all means do it, if that is what you need.

Don't go overboard.  But your particular problem seems like an example where a trigger could be quite useful.

Do realize that there might be other solutions.  For instance, perhaps a view would do what you want:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*
    from t
    where col1 is not null or col2 is not null or . . .;
```

This would save all the overhead of the trigger.  If the table got too big, you could delete the all-`NULL` rows using a scheduled job.